# Cannot resolve BasicConfigurator class on Log4j-core 2.3

Tags: apache, selenium, log4j, webdriver

I'm trying to use log4j on my selenium testing and I use maven to import log4j in my project. By going to mvnrepository.com I searched for apache log4j and added the Apache log4j 1.2.17 in my project but there was around 50 artifact missing errors displayed. I checked back to mvnrepository, It has a note that the log4j 1.2.17 was moved to New Group: org.apache.logging.log4j and New Artifact: log4j-core.

I added the Log4j-core 2.3 dependency on my maven project but the BasicConfigurator class cannot be resolved. I search for the class list of Log4j-core 2.3 and found out that the BasicConfigurator class is not part of the package. Only the Log4j 1.2.17 has this class.

How can I successfully import the BasicConfigurator class in my maven project? What Dependency do I need?

Thanks!

Comment: Same problem here. Did you solve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BasicConfigurator replacement in log4j2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41442024/basicconfigurator-replacement-in-log4j2)

Answer (score 0):

This will work in log4j2-
**ConfigurationSource configSource = new ConfigurationSource(logConfigurationStream);
Configurator.initialize(null, configSource);**

or you can make a use of Logger context by setting the configlocation in the following way-
**LoggerContext context  = (LoggerContext)LogManager.getContext(false);
context.setConfigLocation(new File(//log4j2.xmlPath).toURI());**