# BasicConfigurator replacement in log4j2

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

I am working on a log4j 1 to log4j 2 migration. Inside a AppConfigInitializer file we use something like this -

```
BasicConfigurator.configure(consoleAppender);
```

What shall I replace this with to get it working in log4j2. I am using the backward compatibility bridge as well but that has broken BasicConfigurator implementation.

I think I need to do this using config file, but not able to find how.

Comment: Please refer this link : [Very simple log4j2 XML configuration file using Console and File appender](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21206993/very-simple-log4j2-xml-configuration-file-using-console-and-file-appender).

Comment: Thanks a lot. In that case, I should not even put anything in code? This is for a test package. So shall I just create the config file and remove all the setup code ? And it will auto initialize things reading from config file.

Comment: Yes either do in code or in config file.Refer [Apache log4j 2 docs](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The solution above works, but since default log level is ERROR, not all logs are shown. Log level can be adjusted with Configurator.setRootLevel method:

```
    Configurator.initialize(new DefaultConfiguration());
    Configurator.setRootLevel(Level.INFO);
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer. Avoid use just code as answer.

Answer (score 6):

```
Configurator.initialize(new DefaultConfiguration());
```